# Ng-hide or ng-show based on user roles

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, html

Good morning developers,

I have been instructed to assign user roles to specific views. I got three roles:

- Power user ( can edit, can delete)
- Viewer(no edit, no delete)
- Basic (no edit)

This is what I got in code:

**HTML5 and AngularJS:**

```
<button ng-click="vm.openSettings(vm.selected, $event)" class="btn btn-default"  ng-hide="vm.viewmode === 1 || !vm.selected" ><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>&nbsp;Settings</button>
<button ng-click="vm.deleteProject(vm.selected, $event)" class="btn btn-default" ng-hide="vm.viewmode === 1 || !vm.selected" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>&nbsp;Delete</button>`
```

**JS:**

```
function getUsers() {
    var d = $q.defer();
    var url = '/api/sso/getusers';
    $http.get(url)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           d.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           logger.error(data);
           d.reject();
        });
     return d.promise;
  }
```

How can I hide the delete and edit button based on the user roles in the database?

Comment: `$http` service already returns promise so there is no need for creating deffered object, just `return $http.get(url).then(function (result) { return result.data; });`

Comment: How do you gonna get the roles from the database? I mean is it as an array of strings or array of objects?

Comment: An array of Json objects

Comment: In the questions tags there is a tag called c# is this the language of your backend? are you using .net?

Comment: Yes this is for my backend security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest u use the `ng-if` functionality for hiding content that a user never have to see.

Your queston can be answered in many ways. But I will try to explain an usefull reusable method.

```html
<!-- From the html only call exact functions in your controller -->
<div ng-controller="TestController as vm">
    <button ng-if="vm.hasEditRights()">Editbutton</button>
    <button ng-if="vm.hasCreateRights()">Createbutton</button>
</div>
```

```js
myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'UserService', 
    function($scope, UserService) {

    var vm = this;
    // The functions in the controllers define the actual rights for the functionality
    vm.hasEditRights = function() {
        // Check rights in the UserService with a list of roles that are allowed to this functionality. 
        // This way you can assign multiple roles to 1 functionality.
        // Implement the UserService.hasRole function to check the role of the logged in user 
        // (if the user role is available in the list of roles given than the function will return true)
        return UserService.hasRole([Role.PowerUser])
    };
    vm.hasCreateRights = function() {
        return UserService.hasRole([Role.PowerUser, Role.Basic])
    };
}]);
```

EDIT: Added example of the UserService.hasRole function

```
var user; // represents the user object
xxx.hasRole = function(allowedRoles) {
    if (angular.isUndefined(allowedRoles)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (angular.isUndefined(user) || angular.isUndefined(user.role)) {
        return false;
    }
   return allowedRoles.indexOf(user.role) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: I am gonna try this!

Answer (score 0):

below is an example for the Editor user for the Edit button
consider to put your outside conditions inside if possible, otherwise do as below :

```
 ng-hide="hideEdit(vm.viewmode === 1 || !vm.selected)"
```

and in your angular code do your logic

```
$scope.hideEdit = function (outsideConditions) {

   var currentUser = userServie.getUsers().currentUser() // get your user 
   if(!currentUser.Editor & outsideConditions) {
      return true;  // hide the button
     }
     else {
          return false; //show the button
        }
  }
```

hope this helps 
cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Need some more information to provide you a solution. Can you provide some sample data that is coming from your $http call? Here is a basic solution that you can do:

Normally your data must must contain a property to distinguish user roll and that will be used to render your view. Now if you use ng-show/ng-hide in this situation then anyone can use browser's inspection tool and make it visible and can be easily click your button. So I suggest you to use template there so that according to your need the view of that portion will render. Let me know if you have anything to discuss about this.

Thanks.